# What is the better way to fill polygons?

Tags: 3d

I wrote a simple 3d render application which loads a 3d model from .obj file. Can someone tell me what is the better way to fill each polygon with one colour? I thought about scanning each polygon and setting pixel within the boundaries or scanning the whole screen and do the same process in one go line by line. My object is being rendered every second because there is a constant rotation around Y axis. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fill polygons with colors, you always have to [deal with visibility](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.838/S98/meetings/m23/alglist.html) of polygons, so as usual the [z-buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering) together bind with rasterization is the best time-tested way..